# Join element in an array and separate with space

Tags: perl, join

I want to join the first to 16th word and 17th to 31st, etc in an array with space to one line but do not know why the code does not work. Hope to get help here.Thanks

```
my @file = <FILE>;
for ( $i=0; $i<=$#file; $i+=16 ){
    my $string = join ( " ", @file[$i..$i+15] );
    print FILE1 "$string\n";
}
```

Below is part of my file.

```
1
2
3
...
```

What i wan to print is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21....
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't do it the way you've done it.

Instead I would:

```
open ( my $input, '<', "your_file_name" ) or die $!;
chomp ( my @file = <$input> ); 
print join (" ",splice (@file, 0, 15)),"\n" while @file;
```

Note - I've used a lexical file handle with a 3 argument open, because that's better style.

`splice` removes the first 16 elements from `@file` each iteration, and continues until `@file` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your lines have newlines attached to them. Remove them with [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html). Then loop over the array, remove 16 items and print them.

```
my @file = <FILE>;
chomp @file;

while (@file) {
    my @temp;
INNER: for ( 0 .. 15 ) {
        push @temp, shift @file || last INNER; # not or
    }
    print join( q{ }, @temp ), "\n";
}
```

This is the long implementation of [the `splice` solution Sobrique suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108640/join-element-in-an-array-and-separate-with-space/44108685?noredirect=1#comment75236888_44108685). It's does the same thing, just way more verbose.

---

This is the old answer before the edit:

If you only want the first 16, this is way more effective.

```
my $string = join q{ }, map { <FILE>; chomp; $_ } 1 .. 16;
```

This reads 16 lines and `chomp` each of them, then `join`s.

You might also want to use lexical file handles `$fh` instead of the GLOB `FILE`.

```
open my $fh, '<', $path_to_file or die $!;
```

Comment: Would it be worth mentioning `splice` at this point? Because I'd probably use that: `print join (" ",splice (@file, 0, 15)),"\n" while @file;`. Not directly relevant to the answer though.

Comment: @Sobrique hmm, maybe. I think reading all the file is inefficient though. See my update.

Comment: The example has a second row.... I had assumed it was reading the whole thing in chunks of 16 lines.

Comment: @Sobrique I saw that. But the text says otherwise. It's not clear. If the example is correct, your `splice` makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque , i want to read all the text, sorry that my question is not clear, i edited the question and posted again.

Comment: @Sobrique do you want to post your `splice` solution yourself?

Comment: @simbabque, even i use chomp my output file still empty with one more empty line, is it the problem of the file i open?

Comment: The last empty line would be from the final `"\n"` @tim. If you don't want that, don't `print` directly. Collect the `join`ed stuff and then `join` it on `"\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if you want to read it from file, don't store the whole file into an array. Instead loop through line by line. And check the line number with `$.` special variable.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $fh,"<","input.txt";
my $line;
while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;

    $line.= $_." ";

    print "$line\n" and $line="" if($. % 16 == 0);

    END{ print "$line\n";};
}
```

Or this also will work

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open my $wh,"<","input.txt";
my $line;
foreach (;;)
{
    my $data = join " ",(map { my $m=<$wh> || ""; chomp($m); $m} (0..15));

    last if ($data =~m/^\s+$/);

    print $data,"\n";   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have FILE and FILE1 descriptors open, try:

```
$.%16?s!\s+! !:1 and print FILE1 $_ while <FILE>;
```